# Removing reverse duplicates from a nested like - python

Tags: python, list, duplicates

Im working on a code that removes the duplicate elements from a list. The duplicates order can be different but I'd still consider the two the same.

For example i'd consider `[[m, b], [c, d]]` and `[[c, d], [m, b]]` to de duplicates.

Im working on a code that would recognize these as duplicate and remove the extra on from the overall list. So far Im trying it out on a list with no duplicates whatsoever, so the end list should be unchanged.

This is the list,

```
A= [[[a1, b1], [a1, b1]],
 [[a2, b2], [a2, b2]],
 [[a3, b3], [a3, b3]],
 [[a4, b4], [a4, b4]]]
```

The code Im using is,

```
for i in A:
    for j in A:
        if j[1]== i[0]:
            if j[0]==i[1]:
                A.remove(j)
```

I want the code to compare the second element in given inner list (j[1]) with the first element in one of the other inner lists (i[0]) and similar for j[0] and i[1], and if they are equal (ie i and j are duplicates of each other) then one of the elements is removed from the list.

The issue is that with this code the output should not have been different from the starting list (A), however the result was this,

```
[[[a2, b2], [a2, b2]], [[a4, b4], [a4, b4]]]
```

Im just looking for input of why this might've happened and how to alter my code to avoid the problem.

Comment: Don't remove items from a list as you're iterating over it.

Comment: Im not sure I understand? Isn't the code asking to only remove an element fs the conditions are met?

Comment: The loop condition `for i in A` is evaluated _once_, when the loop begins. At that point the code "remembers" all of the elements in the list.  But if you remove elements from the list  inside the loop, then the actual state of the list falls out of sync with the "remembered" state, and bad things happen.

Comment: You need some way to ensure `i` and `j` are not _the same item_.  As an example, on the very first inner loop iteration, `i` and `j` are both `[[a1, b1], [a1, b1]]` because they're _the same item_, and thus that item gets removed.

Comment: Perhaps `if i is j: continue` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've got it:

```
B = A.copy()
C = A.copy()
for index, element in enumerate(B):
    try:
        if set(B[index][0]) == set(C[index + 1][0]) or set(B[index][1]) == set(C[index + 1][1]):
            A.remove(element)
    except:
        pass
```

In the case of

```
A = [
    [['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b1']],
    [['a2', 'b2'], ['b2', 'a2']],
    [['a3', 'b3'], ['a3', 'b3']],
    [['a4', 'b4'], ['a4', 'b4']]
]
```

This returns A

While if you have:

```
A = [
    [['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b1']],
    [['a1', 'b1'], ['b1', 'a1']],
    [['a3', 'b3'], ['a3', 'b3']],
    [['a4', 'b4'], ['a4', 'b4']]
]
```

It returns:

```
A = [
    [['a1', 'b1'], ['b1', 'a1']],
    [['a3', 'b3'], ['a3', 'b3']],
    [['a4', 'b4'], ['a4', 'b4']]
]
```

In your code, it didn't work because you were deleting elements from what you were iterating over. Also, checking whether lists equal each other won't tell you if they contain the same elements, i.e. `[a,b] == [b,a]` returns `False`. You would need to compare sets instead.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

To compare the intersection of two lists, it can be helpful to use **sets**, especially if your lists have more than two elements.

```
a = ['m', 'n']
b = ['n', 'o']
print(set(a) & set(b)) # The & operator returns the intersecting elements

-> {'n'}
```

As for your question, this code should work:

```
for a in A:
  B = A.copy()
  B.remove(a) # so you don't compare a to a and mark it as a duplicate
  for b in B:
    if set(b[0]) & set(b[1]):
      A.remove(b)
```

Comment: Hi, I just checked this and it returns:

[[['a1', 'b1'], ['a1', 'b1']]]

Which I don't think is right

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> def remove_duplicates(A):
...     for sublist in A:
...             sublist.sort()
...     B = []
...     for sublist in A:
...             if sublist not in B:
...                     B.append(sublist)
...     return B
... 
>>> A = np.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=(8, 2)).tolist()
>>> A
[[0, 1], [1, 0], [0, 2], [0, 0], [2, 2], [2, 2], [0, 2], [1, 0]]
>>> remove_duplicates(A)
[[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 0], [2, 2]]
```

Tested on python 3.7.7.